# How to connect to CPanel "web disk" implementation of webDAV fom c# application

Tags: c#, cpanel, webdav

I am trying to connect to Cpanel implementation of webDAV from a c# application.(to hopefully later create directories and upload files.

The configuration script specifies a URL in the form

\\[DOMAIN]@SSL@2078\DavWWWRoot

I can mount the drive in windows using the URL and my username and password

I have tried using the webdav client nuget package as follows - but get cannot parse the uri as is expecting a http:// address

```
try
{
    this.webDavClient_Auth.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    this.webDavClient_Auth.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);

    this.webDavClient_Client = new WebDavClient(this.webDavClient_Auth);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    messageStatusWindow("ERROR: Problem with setting up the webDAV Client " + ex.Message);
}
```

And also another method recommended for mounting a "file share" directly and this method cannot parse the url again

```
        try
        {
            NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
            CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
            theNetCache.Add(new Uri(baseUrl), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
            string[] theFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(baseUrl);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            messageStatusWindow("ERROR: Problem with setting up the webDAV Client " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Can anyone shed any light on either method and how I can pass the server details or have any examples of connecting to a cpanel webdisk (webdav) from c#.

Any help apreciated.

Comment: The address `\\[DOMAIN]@SSL@2078\DavWWWRoot` is not WebDAV, but the normal SMB shares that Windows uses. WebDAV goes in fact though http/https, so the error is normal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is exactly my problem, what method and what type of address would I use to connect to this web share  from a c# application ie the configuration scripts that is generated for linux is davs://[DOMAIN]:2078

Comment: Additionally I am getting Client Attempt by method 'WebDav.WebDavClient..ctor(WebDav.WebDavClientParams)' to access method 'WebDav.WebDavClient.ConfigureHttpClient(WebDav.WebDavClientParams)' failed. I am not too sure where to go from here.